# Plotting a multidimensional Data Set

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization, shiny

I have a 2 dimensional data set (matrix/data frame) that looks like this

```
              779      482      859     1156
maxs          56916.00 78968.00 51156.00 44827.01
Means+Stdv    41784.70 64440.83 38319.10 42767.14
Mean_Cost     31863.18 44407.40 29365.78 38711.29
Means_Stdv    21941.66 24373.97 20412.45 34655.43
mins          21088.00 13768.00 24132.00 31452.00
```

The 779, 489,859, 1156 are values that I want to draw on the x-axis

The rest of the values on the column are values that correpond to each x

Now I want to plot the entire data set, so that I have a graph with the the following points

(779,56916) , (779, 41784)......

(482,78968) , (482, 64440)..... and so on

The way I did it so far is like this (it gives me the plot I am looking for)

```
plot(colnames(resultsSummary),resultsSummary[1,],ylim=c(0,80000),pch=6)
points(colnames(resultsSummary),resultsSummary[2,],pch=3)
points(colnames(resultsSummary),resultsSummary[3,])
```

and so on..... plotting row by row

I am sure there is a better way to do it, but I dont know how, any suggestions?

Comment: If you're asking for a "better way," what are the criteria you wish to use to determine what's better? If you get the plot you want, what's the problem?

Comment: I find 6 lines to produce one plot of a small dataset a lot of code, and I assumed there is a better way (compacter?) of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="              779      482      859     1156
maxs          56916.00 78968.00 51156.00 44827.01
Means+Stdv    41784.70 64440.83 38319.10 42767.14
                 Mean_Cost     31863.18 44407.40 29365.78 38711.29
                 Means_Stdv    21941.66 24373.97 20412.45 34655.43
                 mins          21088.00 13768.00 24132.00 31452.00", 
              header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
m <- as.matrix(DF)
matplot(as.integer(colnames(m)),
        t(m), pch=seq_len(ncol(m)))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 1):

Following also works:

```
ddf = structure(list(var = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("maxs", 
"Mean_Cost", "Means_Stdv", "Means+Stdv", "mins"), class = "factor"), 
    X779 = c(56916, 41784.7, 31863.18, 21941.66, 21088), X482 = c(78968, 
    64440.83, 44407.4, 24373.97, 13768), X859 = c(51156, 38319.1, 
    29365.78, 20412.45, 24132), X1156 = c(44827.01, 42767.14, 
    38711.29, 34655.43, 31452)), .Names = c("var", "X779", "X482", 
"X859", "X1156"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))

ddf
         var     X779     X482     X859    X1156
1       maxs 56916.00 78968.00 51156.00 44827.01
2 Means+Stdv 41784.70 64440.83 38319.10 42767.14
3  Mean_Cost 31863.18 44407.40 29365.78 38711.29
4 Means_Stdv 21941.66 24373.97 20412.45 34655.43
5       mins 21088.00 13768.00 24132.00 31452.00

ddf[6,2:5]=as.numeric(substr(names(ddf)[2:5],2,4))
ddf2 = data.frame(t(ddf))
ddf2 = ddf2[-1,]
mm = melt(ddf2, id='X6')
ggplot(mm)+geom_point(aes(x=X6, y=value, color=variable))
```

[image]